# Screen not working on water damaged iPhone and can't disable Find My iPhone to restore

Tags: iphone, ios, screen, find-my-iphone, damage

I've got a got water damaged iPhone and the screen no longer allows me to see anything at all. It turns on fine and I think in some parts the touch sensors work as well. I could use Siri yesterday but now I try to use Siri, it keeps saying unavailable and connect to the internet.

I need to turn off Find My iPhone so I can restore it to its factory settings but when I go into iCloud from another device it says its offline. I've tried checking to see if calls can come in but no luck and I've tried swiping up and tapping where airplane mode would be but still no use.

Any ideas on what I can do to so I can get my phone back online again so I can at least use it to call and attempt to disable Find My iPhone? It can be seen by iTunes if that's any help?

iPhone 5, iOS 7.1.2

Comment: I'd say - Genius bar would be next port of call

Comment: As soon as the device is off (and therefor offline) you can go to iCloud.com and choose "remove from account" to deactivate find my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You can just put your device into DFU mode, which bypasses the Find My iPhone requirement. To put the device in DFU mode:

1. Connect the device to a computer running the most recent version of iTunes (can be downloaded at https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/)
2. Hold down the Home button and the Sleep/Wake button for 10 seconds
3. Once 10 seconds has elapsed then release the Sleep/Wake button
4. Keep holding the Home button until the device appears in iTunes

*If you need more help getting your device into DFU mode look at http://www.iclarified.com/1034/how-to-put-an-iphone-into-dfu*

From here you will be able to restore your device using iTunes.